# Nix derivation to bundle multiple programs

Tags: nix

I'm trying to write a derivation that will install a few executables. I can do this pretty easily with symlinkJoin

```
{pgm-a, pgm-b, symlinkJoin}: symlinkJoin {
  name = "pgm-env";
  paths = [pgm-a,pgm-b]; }
```

However, if `pgm-a` or `pgm-b` have already been installed I get an error  involving conflicting packages...

```
...'<pgm-a>/bin/pgm-a' and '<pgm-env>/bin/pgm-a' have the same priority 5; use 'nix-env --set-flag priority NUMBER INSTALLED_PKGNAME' ...
```

Is there a way to make a suite of executables available in the environment but would only add to the environment what was needed (or otherwise circumvent this error)?

Some background:
I've started curating a private repository for my lab. We set up VM networks, install some software, do some tests, rinse and repeat. No one but me is a Nix user so I want to keep the nix part as low key as possible--I don't want the user to have to set the priority flag nor do I want to make them use `nix-shell`. They are all used to doing `apt-get install ...` so my plan is to have them do `nix-env -i` instead and provide packages like `ourExperiment-x` that gets them most of the way to properly configured VMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, you can set packages priority when declaring it directly like this:

```
{pgm-a, pgm-b, symlinkJoin}: symlinkJoin {
  name = "pgm-env";
  paths = [pgm-a,pgm-b];
  meta.priority = 10;
}
```

The default priority is 5, and lower priorities get priority over higher ones, so by setting it to 10, the files of this derivation will only be used as a fallback.